# Element property in polymer 1.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

in Polymer 0.5 it was possible to set an element on an element via something like 
    scrollTarget="{{$.scroller}}"

Is this possible with 1.0? There is a element-property (positionTarget) for example in iron-dropdown. But I do not find an example for that..

Kind regards!

Comment: Are you asking how to add a property to your own custom element? If so look [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html) for how to do that.

Comment: No, thanks, thats clear. I want to have an Element as property in my Element. Like in iron-dropdown. But i can't find a way to set it from outside..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it imperatively:

```
this.$.myDropdown.positionTarget = this.$.targetElement;
```

or you could do it partially declaratively:

```
positionTarget="[[getElement('targetElement')]]"
```

where getElement is defined as:

```
getElement: function(element) {
  return this.$[element];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is no longer possible. If you look at the [migration guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#binding-to-sibling-elements), it describes that binding to sibling properties is not supported anymore. While you are not trying to bind a property, but to the element itself, you require the same syntax with the $ sign, which appears to have been removed.